# I want my homepage to contain the contents of another page. How do i do this?

Tags: php, html

I want my website's homepage to show the same content as another page. I don't want it to redirect the URL, or to mask it. I'm aware of php include, but that'd mean the other page would have to link all it's files and images differently. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the content to work just as the original works? I know one could use an API to grab a picture of a webpage and display. (Google does this quite often.)

Comment: Are you looking for an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: "I don't want it to redirect the URL, or to mask it" - I think those are the only 2 logical options - no? Either you redirect (which means you DON'T mask), or you mask (which means you don't redirect) ?

Comment: wget with the recursive switch.

Comment: Could you not use `include`? Set the images, scripts, links etc to absolute paths to avoid missing files. Or load the file contents using `file_get_contents` and then provide a regex search and replace to re-source the assets. Then print out the file's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this simply by using the cURL PHP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe, or object tag

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't want to use it inside of a frame though, I want it to mirror the page.

Comment: You could also add a text between the `<iframe>` tags for browsers that do not support iframes!

Answer (score 0):

frameset are supposed to be obsolete in HTML5, but maybe it can help here...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <frameset framespacing="0" rows="0,*" frameborder="0" noresize>
        <frame name="top" src="_blank" target="top">
        <frame name="main" src="http://www.perdu.com" target="main">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: google.com was a bad example because they implement a security feature to disable this. Some other websites may do the same.